# Spain visa: bank statement less than 3 months old

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I'm a Non-EU student studying in the UK.

Is it possible to apply for the Spain visa with a bank statement less than 3 months? Mine is only 2 and a half months because that's how long I've been in the UK.

Comment: I think this is a valid Travel question. Why is the close votes?

Comment: This question is confusing.  Is it possible to apply for *what*?

Comment: @NateEldredge Spain (schengen) visa, the title says it..

Comment: @HaLaBi sorry but the title doesnt say it. It's not really clear what is asked here

Comment: Meant Spain visa yes. I've edited the question to include that. anybody with experience applying through the spanish embassy?

Comment: It's still quite hard to understand what you're asking.  I realise English is possibly not your first language, but let me try and work this out.  You're saying you want a Spanish Schengen visa? And you need to provide 3 months worth of Bank statements, but only have 2.5?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **no**. It's a requirement from the embassy to provide bank statements for the last three months, and if you haven't had a bank account that long your Schengen visa application is very likely to be rejected.